# Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

Can anyone help me complete this? I'm a beginner and this is my first time using Laravel and PHP.

```php
<?php

@foreach ($peminjaman as $value)
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->no_peminjaman }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->no_bmn }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->no_seri }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->kelengkapan }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Show us your controller code.

Comment: can we see the full code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add links(), so that the links for pagination can be generated in your view.Just have a look at the documentation here and you're good to go:https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you do :

`$peminjaman = Model::paginate(10);`

The `$peminjaman` is an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`.

In your case it seems like somewhere you have `$peminjaman->id` which as a result throwing the error you mentioned.

There is no property called `id` present on the `LengthAwarePaginator` paginator instance.